# Create a search "engine" to get information from a Google DataStore in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search-engine

I'm looking for some information to create a search engine to search information from my DataStore.

I have build a datastore and I can seach information from it with queries (my datatstore store information of matches of différents sport, the date, the competitio, the pool, the score of each team, who have made the goal...) ! But now I would like to have a kind of search engine like google that allow me to search information in my datastore... For example if I want all goal from a team I would have to write "All goal from Germany"... And if I want all goal of a comptetition that have more that 3 goals, I would have to write "All goal of COMPETITION where goal > 3". But I have no idea how to do that !

Do you ?

Thank you if you can help me, it would be awsome to have that !

(I'm working in python and HTML for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write an intermediate layer that will convert the query like

```
All goal from Germany
```

to something like

```
filter(Goal.country == Germany)
```

its not possible directly. but with an intermediate layer it can be done

Answer (score 0):

It's important to first get yourself familiar with [Datastore indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes) first as it can affect your data model and will help you understand the rest.  Any property (or combination thereof) you want to filter or sort on will need to be indexed.  There's an in-depth article on datastore indexes [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection).

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) also provides a good introduction to querying your data with the *ndb* API.

(Disclaimer: I've only used Java with App Engine but the concepts are the same).